# Alternative to DISPLAY.getWidth()

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I know the `Display` method `getWidth()` has been deprecated since API 13. I have the following line of code:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
```

What is the alternative for API Level 13 and above?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize), you need to use `getSize(Point outSize)`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're not in an activity use

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `getSize(Point outSize)` (according to [official android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getHeight%28%29) )

Hope this helps!